# Is there a way to retrieve the 'index' of a RegExp search as opposed to the 'lastIndex'?

Tags: javascript, regex

Ok peeps.. So I have a string variable that contains the `outerHTML` of a table element. It's not my handy-work and it's *messy*, there's white-space everywhere, unnecessary line-breaks and the likes...

I was going to attempt to write some js to **xify** or 'tidy up' the code, tabify the lines, remove the white-space etc, when I decided to at long last take a gander at how **RegExp** worked in the searching of a string...

I am in the process of understanding how the **RegExp**`.lastIndex` property works and as part of the visual tuition I wanted to display the string I was searching in the console with colored styling round the expression at the location of the search results...

And there-in lies my problem. If I want to encompass the expression(s) searched for with `%c` in order to style it, I require both the starting and the ending index(lastIndex) of the expression...

Now I can handle this if the expression is a word like `/hello/`, I just subtract the length of the `.source` property. But what if the expressions is `/\w/`, indicative of anything that is a word.

**Q.** How would I go about finding the index of the beginning of the word(s)?

Below is an ***example*** of what I am trying to achieve. At the moment the call `str.src(exp_3)` performs no action, but the `console.warn()` below it demonstrates what result I want to achieve from said call.

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype,'src',{value:function(e){
    src = e.source;
    if(src[0] != '\\')          len = src.length;
        else if(src == '\\s')   len = 1;
            else                len = 0;
    aEd  = [];
    aSty = [];
    prev = 0;
    while( e.test(this) ){
        f = e.lastIndex;
        s = f-len;
        if(s)   aEd.push( this.slice(prev, s) );
        aEd.push('%c', this.slice(s,f), '%c');
        aSty.push('background:teal;color:silver', '');
        prev = f;
    }
    aEd.push( this.slice(f,this.length) );
    sEd = aEd.join('');
    sx  = '"'+ sEd +'","'+ aSty.join('","') +'"';
    eval('console.log('+sx+')');
}});

$(document).ready(function(){
    str   = 'Is this all this is?';
    exp_1 = /is/gi;
    exp_2 = /\s/g;
    exp_3 = /\w/g;

    str.src(exp_1);
    str.src(exp_2);
    str.src(exp_3);

    console.warn(
        '%cIs%c %cthis%c %call%c %cthis%c %cis?%c',
        'background:teal;color:silver','',
        'background:teal;color:silver','',
        'background:teal;color:silver','',
        'background:teal;color:silver','',
        'background:teal;color:silver',''
    );
});
```

Be kind peeps, I did say I was ***learning***...

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what problem you're trying to solve with this. Could you simplify the problem?

Comment: please just run the code in chrome console, i want the '.log()' that is displayed for the `str.src(exp_3)` call to look identical to that of the '.warn()'. `lastIndex` on a loop would give me the index at the end of every word, how do I get the index at the start of every word? surely when an expression is found `lastIndex` is derived from something like `string.indexOf(..)+expression.source.length` so how do I access the `string.indexOf(..)` if there is one. Apologies I can't really tone it down as I don't know how to explain it any better:(

Comment: Is there a reason you'd want to do it this way rather than using an existing XML beautifier like [vkbeautify](https://code.google.com/p/vkbeautify/)?

Comment: didn't think to check for a 'beautifier', didn't even know that was their name, just thought to write one? will take a look though now I know cheers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were real close to the solution.

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype,'src',{value:function(e){
    src = e.source;
    aEd  = [];
    aSty = [];
    prev = 0;

    while( match = e.exec(this)){
        f = e.lastIndex;
        s = match.index;
        if(s)   aEd.push( this.slice(prev, s) );
        aEd.push('%c', this.slice(s,f), '%c');
        aSty.push('background:teal;color:silver', '');
        prev = f;
    }
    aEd.push( this.slice(f,this.length) );
    sEd = aEd.join('');
    sx  = '"'+ sEd +'","'+ aSty.join('","') +'"';
    eval('console.log('+sx+')');
}});

$(document).ready(function(){
    str   = 'Is this all this is?';
    exp_1 = /is/gi;
    exp_2 = /\s/g;
    exp_3 = /\w/g;

    str.src(exp_1);
    str.src(exp_2);
    str.src(exp_3);

    console.warn(
        '%cIs%c %cthis%c %call%c %cthis%c %cis?%c',
        'background:teal;color:silver','',
        'background:teal;color:silver','',
        'background:teal;color:silver','',
        'background:teal;color:silver','',
        'background:teal;color:silver',''
    );
});
```

By the way, a '?' is not considered a word-character.

Comment: dude you're a life saver, i thought this was gonna go cold, thought i'd over explained it... is see what you're saying reference the `e.exec()` to a variable in order to call the index! genius... I didn't know a `RegExp` even had an index property.. again thanks. will test it then accept the answer